# save and load highscore

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

i tried to use NSUserDefults to save and load a highscore(nsinteger) for my game. 
i created an void function that check if the gameoverscore is bigger than my highscore and if it does to switch between them. i want that every time the game is over there will be a label which show my currect highscore.
to do this, i create a property for my NSUsweDefults, in my viewdidload i tried to load the currect highscore, and another function (checkIfHighscore).
here is my NSUserDefults property:

```
@property(readwrite) NSUserDefaults *prefs;
```

here is my viewdidload code:

```
    NSInteger currectHighscore =  [prefs integerForKey:@"highscore"];
    highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currectHighscore];
```

here is my checkIfHighscore:

```
-(void)checkIfHighScore
{
    if(gameOverScore > highScore)
    {
        highScore = gameOverScore;
        [self newHighscoreAnimation];

        [prefs setInteger:highScore forKey:@"highscore"];
        [prefs synchronize];

    }
    highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Highscore:  %d", highScore];
}
```

when i enter to this viewcontroller my highscorelabel shows 0, like it doesnt save my highscore.

what do i do wrong?
thanks!

Comment: You don't tell us what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Snippet used to save your highscore in the prefs.
int highScore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


// Snippet used to get your highscore from the prefs.
highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
```