# Save an int value, and load then app loads

Tags: iphone

I'm making an app that changes images every time the user press on the screen. It is using an int to know then to change image.

I need help to save the int value then screen is pressed and load it then the app is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `NSUserDefaults` class for this:

```
// Write
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:7615 forKey:@"customIntegerValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Read
NSLog(@"Integer = %i", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"customIntegerValue"];
```

Answer (score 1):

// To save in pref

```
int highScore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

// To get saved value from  pref

```
highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
```

You can see similar post here: [stackOldPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365352/save-and-load-highscore/11365543#11365543)

Answer (score 0):

You can save values in `NSUserDefaults *defaults                = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`