# Saving NSInteger intScore when application is closed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I made an app with xcode 4, all code is in the main code file so i don't have more classes.
I have 3 views but only use one at the moment. Now in the game i save an integer as score, and at the end of the game it shows what your score is, but i wanted to know how i can let that int show up in a label in one of my other 2 views, and how i can keep it there when the application is restarted. I'm sorry of my bad english but i'm new to this objective C and iphone Apps. Thank You!

**and how do i put something in an other viewcontroller, can't fine codefile**

this is the code:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Mundo Grafia
//
//  Created by Axel Lambregts on 2/10/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 AxelNiels. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController


// variabelen aanmaken
NSInteger intScore;
NSInteger intRandomMonument;
NSInteger intRandomAnswerPosition;
NSInteger intRandomAnswerA;
NSInteger intRandomAnswerB;
NSInteger intRandomAnswerC;
NSInteger intRandomAnswerD;
NSInteger intArrayEuropeLenght;
NSInteger intAmountOfQuestionsAsked;
NSString *scoreSpatie;
NSString *arrEurope[][2] =

    {

        {@"Eifel.jpg",@"Paris"},
        {@"NotreDame.jpg",@"Paris"},
        {@"ArcDeTriompheParis.jpg",@"Paris"},

        {@"AtomuimBrussels.jpg",@"Brussels"},
        {@"MannekePis.jpg",@"Brussels"},

        {@"Colosseum.jpg",@"Rome"},
        {@"TreviFountainRome.jpg",@"Rome"},

        {@"SagradaFamilia.jpg",@"Barcelona"},
        {@"SpanishSchoolMadrid.jpg",@"Madrid"},

        {@"KremlinMoskou.jpg",@"Moskou"},

        {@"MermaidKopenhagen.jpg",@"Copenhagen"},

        {@"MonteCarloMonaco.jpg",@"Monaco"},

        {@"AcropolisAthens.jpg",@"Athens"},

        {@"ParlementBudapest.jpg",@"Budapest"},

        {@"BuildingReykjavik.jpg",@"Reykjavik"},

        {@"StatueKiev.jpg",@"Kiev"},

        {@"PortOfEuropeLissabon.jpg",@"Lisbon"},

        {@"ViewSanMarino.jpg",@"San Marino"},

        {@"BridgesPrague.jpg",@"Prague"},

        {@"MoskeeAnkara.jpg",@"Ankara"},

        {@"TowerBridgeLondon.jpg",@"London"},
        {@"BigBenLondon.jpg",@"London"},
        {@"LondonEyeLondon.jpg",@"London"},

        {@"BrandenburgerTor.jpg",@"Berlin"},
        {@"ReichstagBerlin.jpg",@"Berlin"},

        {nil,nil}

    };


/*
NSArray *arrEurope = @[
@[@"Eifel.jpg",@"Paris"],
@[@"NotreDame.jpg",@"Paris"],
@[@"ArcDeTriompheParis.jpg",@"Paris"],
@[@"Eifel.jpg",@"Paris"],
@[@"NotreDame.jpg",@"Paris"],
@[@"ArcDeTriompheParis.jpg",@"Paris"],

@[@"AtomuimBrussels.jpg",@"Brussels"],
@[@"MannekePis.jpg",@"Brussels"],

@[@"Colosseum.jpg",@"Rome"],
@[@"TreviFountainRome.jpg",@"Rome"],

@[@"SagradaFamilia.jpg",@"Barcelona"],
@[@"SpanishSchoolMadrid.jpg",@"Madrid"],

@[@"KremlinMoskou.jpg",@"Moskou"],

@[@"MermaidKopenhagen.jpg",@"Copenhagen"],

@[@"MonteCarloMonaco.jpg",@"Monaco"],

@[@"AcropolisAthens.jpg",@"Athens"],

@[@"ParlementBudapest.jpg",@"Budapest"],

@[@"BuildingReykjavik.jpg",@"Reykjavik"],

@[@"StatueKiev.jpg",@"Kiev"],

@[@"PortOfEuropeLissabon.jpg",@"Lisbon"],

@[@"ViewSanMarino.jpg",@"San Marino"],

@[@"BridgesPrague.jpg",@"Prague"],

@[@"MoskeeAnkara.jpg",@"Ankara"],

@[@"TowerBridgeLondon.jpg",@"London"],
@[@"BigBenLondon.jpg",@"London"],
@[@"LondonEyeLondon.jpg",@"London"],

@[@"BrandenburgerTor.jpg",@"Berlin"],
@[@"ReichstagBerlin.jpg",@"Berlin"]



];


*/



//methode'start' wanneer er op de start-knop wordt gedrukt
-(IBAction)start{



    [self NewQuestionEurope];
    intAmountOfQuestionsAsked = 0;
    //reset and show score
    intScore = 0;
    score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intScore];

    //make buttons and labels visible
    Start.hidden = YES;
    question.hidden = NO;
    score.hidden = NO;
    scoretext.hidden = NO;
    imageContainer.hidden = NO;


    answerA.hidden = NO;
    answerB.hidden = NO;
    answerC.hidden = NO;
    answerD.hidden = NO;

    answerA.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    answerB.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    answerC.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    answerD.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];


    clickButtonA.hidden = NO;
    clickButtonB.hidden = NO;
    clickButtonC.hidden = NO;
    clickButtonD.hidden = NO;

    GoodFalse.hidden = NO;
    GoodFalse.text=@"Press a button to answer";
    GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   question.text = @"Where is this picture taken?";

}//einde start





-(IBAction)Reset{

score.text= @"gelukt";



}


-(IBAction)NewQuestionEurope{


  if(intAmountOfQuestionsAsked == 19){

      question.text = [@"Uw score is: "stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intScore]];

      Start.hidden = NO;
      question.hidden = NO;
      score.hidden = YES;
      scoretext.hidden = YES;
      imageContainer.hidden = YES;


      answerA.hidden = YES;
      answerB.hidden = YES;
      answerC.hidden = YES;
      answerD.hidden = YES;

      clickButtonA.hidden = YES;
      clickButtonB.hidden = YES;
      clickButtonC.hidden = YES;
      clickButtonD.hidden = YES;
      GoodFalse.hidden = YES;

      Start.titleLabel.text = @"END";



  }

    else{




    intAmountOfQuestionsAsked ++;



    //Deze lus geeft aan intArrayEuropeLenght de waarde van hoeveel rijen de array bevat//
    intArrayEuropeLenght = 0;

    while (arrEurope[intArrayEuropeLenght][0] != NULL)
    {
        intArrayEuropeLenght++;
    }


   //score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intScore];


    scoreSpatie = [
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intScore]
                             stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    score.text = [
                  scoreSpatie
                  stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intAmountOfQuestionsAsked]
                  ];



  // Randoms genereren voor: 4 random antwoorden; 1 random afbeelding; een random positie om het juiste antwoord in te plaatsen
    intRandomMonument = arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght;            
    intRandomAnswerA = arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght;
    intRandomAnswerB = arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght;
    intRandomAnswerC = arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght;
    intRandomAnswerD = arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght;
    intRandomAnswerPosition = arc4random()%4;



    while(arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0] == @"removed"){

        intRandomMonument = arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght; 

    }


  //Random antwoorden maken
    answerA.text = @"";
    answerB.text = @"";
    answerC.text = @"";
    answerD.text = @"";

    if(answerA.text = @""){
        answerA.text = arrEurope[intRandomAnswerA][1];
    }

    if(answerB.text = @""){
        answerB.text = arrEurope[intRandomAnswerB][1];
    }

    if(answerC.text = @""){
        answerC.text = arrEurope[intRandomAnswerC][1];
    }

    if(answerD.text = @""){
        answerD.text = arrEurope[intRandomAnswerD][1];
    }



    switch(intRandomAnswerPosition)
    {
        case 0: answerA.text = arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1];
            break;
        case 1: answerB.text = arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1];
            break;
        case 2: answerC.text = arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1];
            break;
        case 3: answerD.text = arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1];
    };



    //als er antwoorden hetzelfde zijn, voor de gelijke een random blijven maken tot ze niet hetzelfde zijn
    if(
       [answerA.text isEqualToString: answerB.text]||
       [answerA.text isEqualToString: answerC.text]||
       [answerA.text isEqualToString: answerD.text]
       ){

        answerA.text = arrEurope[arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght][1];

    };

    if(
       [answerB.text isEqualToString: answerA.text]||
       [answerB.text isEqualToString: answerC.text]||
       [answerB.text isEqualToString: answerD.text]
       ){

        answerB.text = arrEurope[arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght][1];

    };

    if(
       [answerC.text isEqualToString: answerA.text]||
       [answerC.text isEqualToString: answerB.text]||
       [answerC.text isEqualToString: answerD.text]
       ){

        answerC.text = arrEurope[arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght][1];

    };

    if(
       [answerD.text isEqualToString: answerA.text]||
       [answerD.text isEqualToString: answerB.text]||
       [answerD.text isEqualToString: answerC.text]
       ){

        answerD.text = arrEurope[arc4random()%intArrayEuropeLenght][1];

    };




    //Laat de afbeelding zien van het gekozen monument (via random gekozen)
    imageContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed: arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0]];




  }  

}


//hier onder zit ergens een fout want hij geeft precies random juist en fout :)
//kan zijn dat het opgelost is vanaf we niet 2x dezelfde vragen hebben maar ik denk het niet.

//press buttonA
-(IBAction)AnswerA {



    if([answerA.text isEqualToString: arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1]]){

        GoodFalse.text = @"Correct!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        intScore ++;

    }else {

        GoodFalse.text=@"Wrong!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        }

    arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0] = @"removed";

    [self NewQuestionEurope];

}

//press buttonB
-(IBAction)AnswerB {

    if([answerB.text isEqualToString: arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1]]){

        GoodFalse.text = @"Correct!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        intScore ++;

    }else {

        GoodFalse.text=@"Wrong!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0] = @"removed";
[self NewQuestionEurope];
}

//press buttonC (works)
-(IBAction)AnswerC {


    if([answerC.text isEqualToString: arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1]]){

        GoodFalse.text = @"Correct!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        intScore ++;

    }else {

        GoodFalse.text=@"Wrong!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0] = @"removed";
    [self NewQuestionEurope];
}


//press buttonD
-(IBAction)AnswerD {


    if([answerD.text isEqualToString: arrEurope[intRandomMonument][1]]){

        GoodFalse.text = @"Correct";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        intScore ++;

    }else {

        GoodFalse.text=@"Wrong!";
        GoodFalse.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
   arrEurope[intRandomMonument][0] = @"removed";
    [self NewQuestionEurope];
}





//hier onder niets wijzigen


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Regarding saving the score, check out NSUserDefaults.

Comment: The first thing i want to do is put it in a label thats on an other viewcontrol because saving it for closing the app is not making me worry :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSUserDefaults *scores = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (_points>[scores integerForKey :@"highscore"]) {
    [_highScoresLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_points]];
    [scores setInteger:_points forKey:@"highscore"];
```

I'm using that code to show persistent highscore in one of my game.

to show in another UIViewController simply add this code where _higScoreLabel is the label ypu want the scores to be shown :

```
NSUserDefaults *scores = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *_points = [scores integerForKey :@"highscore"];
[_highScoresLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_points]];
```

Comment: Looks like there are some good answers here to you your question, you should at least set one as correct...

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you know what the user's final score was, write the integer to NSUserDefaults like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:intScore forKey:@"score"];
```

Then, in order to show the score integer in the other view controller, you'll need to just read the value from disk in viewDidLoad of the other viewController, and then set it in the label!
Since the value is already stored on disk, you don't even need to pass it as a parameter or set it as a property on the other viewcontroller, just read it from NSUserDefaults in viewDidLoad (or whatever/whereever method you need to set it).

So in the second viewcontroller, do:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.anotherLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [defaults integerForKey:@"score"]];
}
```

Comment: Ok got a problem; How can i link my label to the second viewer, cause on the normal viewcontroller it works but i cant get the code of the second one

Comment: how do i put something in the second viewcontroller?

Comment: Typically you won't pass a UILabel from view controller to view controller.  I'm not sure what you mean by "put something in the second view controller" or "link my label to the second viewer."  Don't you just want to retrieve the score value from disk in the 2nd view controller, and show it in a label?  If so, in the second view controller's viewDidLoad method, use the code I have above.

Answer (score 0):

// To save in pref

```
int highScore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore]     forKey:@"HighScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

// To get saved value from  pref

```
int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
```

[here is similar question in stack..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365352/save-and-load-highscore/11365543#11365543)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using NSUserDefaults ,it will keep the value in memory until you forcefully remove it or you delete the app.

     int Score = HighScore;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:Score forKey:@"anyKey"];

    currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Score];
    highScoreLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"anyKey"]];
```